# Expected token error in file RecvFile function

Tags: c++, sockets, token

I'm learning some examples about C++ socket. One of the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875735/c-socket-programming-a-client-server-application-to-send-a-file) has an error : "expect token while got fclose" at the line above the last line

The code seems fine with me, so I can't figure out what is wrong here.

Any ideas are appreciated.

```
void RecvFile(int sock, const char* filename) 
{ 
    int rval; 
    char buf[0x1000]; 
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "wb"); 
    if (!file)
    {
        printf("Can't open file for writing");
        return;
    }

    do
    {
        rval = recv(sock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
        if (rval < 0)
        {
            // if the socket is non-blocking, then check
            // the socket error for WSAEWOULDBLOCK/EAGAIN
            // (depending on platform) and if true then
            // use select() to wait for a small period of
            // time to see if the socket becomes readable
            // again before failing the transfer...

            printf("Can't read from socket");
            fclose(file);
            return;
        }

        if (rval == 0)
            break;

        int off = 0;
        do
        {
            int written = fwrite(&buf[off], 1, rval - off, file);
            if (written < 1)
            {
                printf("Can't write to file");
                fclose(file);
                return;
            }

            off += written;
        }
        while (off < rval);
    } 

    fclose(file); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `do` with no corresponding `while`:

```
do
{
    // ...
    do
    {
        // ...
    }
    while (off < rval);
} 
// No while here

fclose(file);
```

It appears that it should just be `while (true)`, which you might as well just stick at the top, instead of doing a `do while`. Execution will break from the loop if `recv` returns 0 or less, which indicate an orderly shutdown and an error respectively. So change it to:

```
while (true)
{
    // ...
    do
    {
        // ...
    }
    while (off < rval);
}

fclose(file);
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is helpful. Voted!

Answer (score 2):

You have a `do` statement without a corresponding `while`:

```
do // <== THERE IS NO CORRESPONDING while FOR THIS do
{
    rval = recv(sock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
    if (rval < 0)
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ...

    do
    {
        // ...
    }
    while (off < rval); // <== This is OK: the "do" has a matching "while"
}
// Nothing here! Should have a "while (condition)"
```

If you just want to repeat your loop indefinitely, then you should use `while (true)` - either replacing the `do` keyword (preferably), or adding it where the missing `while` should go (as indicated by the above comments).

Answer (score 1):

You started a `do` without actually supplying a `while();`

```
do
{
    rval = recv(sock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
    if (rval < 0)
    {
        // if the socket is non-blocking, then check
        // the socket error for WSAEWOULDBLOCK/EAGAIN
        // (depending on platform) and if true then
        // use select() to wait for a small period of
        // time to see if the socket becomes readable
        // again before failing the transfer...

        printf("Can't read from socket");
        fclose(file);
        return;
    }

    if (rval == 0)
        break;

    int off = 0;
    do
    {
        int written = fwrite(&buf[off], 1, rval - off, file);
        if (written < 1)
        {
            printf("Can't write to file");
            fclose(file);
            return;
        }

        off += written;
    }
    while (off < rval);
} //while() Needs to go here

fclose(file);
```